# How can I specify the value of X Label in Matlab figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a matlab figure, where the X and Y vectors are as below:

```
X = [4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024]; 
Y = [1   1.5   2 2.5    3    3    4    4    5]; 
plot(X, Y, 'b-p','LineWidth',1.0);hold on   %
```

The figure is shown as following:

[image]

My concern, can I shown the X_label with specific values,  for example I want the X label to be similar to X, which is `[4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024]`;   similar to the below example:

[image]

When using the function `xticks` or `xticklabels`, that becomes as below:

[image]

However, what I wants is to have equal distance as the figure shown before.

Comment: Have a look at the functions `xticks` and `xticklabels`

Comment: @magnesium That doesn't work as I mentioned above.  I will update my question to show you how that is shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your x-axis is exponential, so what you want is `semilogx` with `xticks` like this:

```
X = [4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024]; 
Y = [1   1.5   2 2.5    3    3    4    4    5]; 
semilogx(X, Y, 'b-p','LineWidth',1.0)
xticks(X);
axis tight
grid on
```

[image]